# How to clean a potentially clogged coleman multifuel stove?

Tags: liquid-fuel-stoves

I've got a coleman Peak 2 stove.

[image]

I tried pure gasoline (which is supports) and a lot of gas spilled out onto the stove and burned black, leaving soot all over it.

Now the stove won't light. I'm not getting any fuel to the burner.

I'm considering:

- Soaking in alcohol
- Soaking in pure gasoline (no additives. It's from walmart and designed for stoves)
- (hardest option) Soaking in carburetor cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

Alcohol can (and does) eat certain types of seals.  Do not use alcohol to clean the stove unless you are certain it is safe for alcohol fuel.  Similarly, carb cleaner is extremely corrosive and will eat many different types of seals/gaskets.

First thing to try is to disassemble and scrub with baking soda, dish soap, and a toothbrush.  If that does not work, then move on to harsher cleansers.

From the coleman website:

> - If there has been a boil-over, remove the screw from the center of each burner and lift off the burner rings and bowl to check the manifold for fluid or food debris. If there is a build-up, clean it with dishwashing soap and warm water before rinsing with clean water.
> - If the stove has a massive amount of grease and dirt build-up inside the case, on the grill or burners, you can take the stove to a car wash and use a high-pressure hose on it. Don't use any type of tire, oven or engine cleaner because it can damage the paint on the inside of the case and the metal of the grate and manifold.
> - If a stove has been cleaned with any type of water hose, turn the stove upside down to ensure all the water is removed from inside the manifold. Any water left inside the manifold can cause it to rust and disturb the flow of fuel to the burner, preventing the stove from burning properly.

You may also have a clogged hose or some other problem.  If you were using it according to the manual and fuel spilled everywhere that would indicate a big issue with your fuel delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I've owned these stoves for years, and am surprised you've got a problem after just one incident. The first thing to know, is that they can be dismantled and re-assembled relatively easily - so if you're feeling adventurous, you can take stuff apart and investigate - but be careful to have a clean surface, and not lose any small bits.

But before all that, have you tried winding the flame control all the way round, beyond the MAX flame point? Doing so should push a fine wire inside the pre-heat tube through the jet, unblocking it in the process. Do it several times, light it, and do it several more times. And tap the whole thing as you go, to knock out any particles.

And one more thing - are these stoves still available somewhere? I live in the UK, and would just love to buy another one, as my (cannibalised/rebuilt) example is on its last legs. No other high altitude stove compaers, in my view!

Pete

Comment: You want to ask the question about the availability of these stores in a separate question. You might get reactions in comments, but that way nobody else will profit from the information too.